# Creating a HTML table with MYSQL fetching data doesn't work

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm attempting to create a dynamic table with MYSQL's function: while(mysql_fetch_assoc).. However, when it fetches more than one result, it doesn't create the table anymore (or fill in the  tags. Excuse me for explaining this incorrectly)

This is my code. Ignore the Dutch words :)

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kostendb WHERE ProjectID = '$_GET[id]'") or die (mysql_error());
echo '
                    <table border="1" style="width:60%">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Kostencode</th>
                        <th>Datum</th>      
                        <th>Bedrag</th>
                    </tr>';
                    while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2))
                    {
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>' .$res['KostenID']. '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' .$res['Datum']. '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' .$res['Bedrag']. '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                echo '</table>';
```

When it finds more than one result, the while-loop doesn't do anything. When it finds just one result, it works fine.

What is causing this, and how can I fix this?

I've checked out an example script, but it's exactly using my method.

Thanks

Comment: Does running the same query in phpMyAdmin returns any results?

Comment: what is the aim of the script your script seems fine

Comment: first of all youre using mysql use mysqli instead also your query does not have any checks to eliminate sql injection threats

Comment: mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kostendb WHERE ProjectID = '{$_GET['id]'}'") or die (mysql_error());

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS Yeah, in phpMyAdmin the query runs just fine.

Comment: @Mr.coder; I appreciate your help, but mysqli has nothing to do with it, and my script does not require a sql injection protection. This is a local project

Comment: @fortune That gives errors

Comment: $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kostendb WHERE ProjectID = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'") or die (mysql_error());

The index for the $_GET-array should be a proper string, shouldn't it?

Comment: @stefan1294 the if you use a newer version of mysql db then you will have a problem with mysql it will throw you an error

Comment: Apparently the way how I solved this, isn't allowed to be an answer. So I'll copy and paste the removed answer: 

Alright, so. For some reason it worked after I rebooted my computer, which was coincidence. I have no idea how this fixed it, but it's solved now...

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You might have mixed mysql with mysqli.
Choose one, don't mix and this might fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

make a variable like $project = $_GET['ID'];

then put in sql statement as ....WHERE Project_ID = $project");

Try this